# Styling an option on a select field - hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have been asked to style the background colour of a dropdown on a hover event.  I tried applying a class class="page-limit-option" to the option element, but no luck. Do I need to create a new style component to use instead of the option?

```
<select class="page-limit"
   id="per-page"
   (change)="onLimitChange($event.target.value)">
   <option class="page-limit-option"
       *ngFor="let option of pageLimitOptions"
       [value]="option.value"
       [selected]="option.value == currentPageLimit"
   >
       {{ option.value }}
   </option>
</select>
```

In the css file :

```
.page-limit {
  background-color: blue;
}

.page-limit-option {
  background-color: red;
}

.page-limit-option:hover {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

stackblitz here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-style-a-select?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: `<option>`s don't respond to events in many browsers. That's one reason numerous different `<select>` replacements are used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not style option as its browser specific feature. So better make a custom select dropdown using div. there you can give colors.

Comment: Exactly that. Create a div based custom dropdown with JS control logic and make the clicked option provide value to a hidden field for example.